# Problems calling shell command from .net core Linux

Tags: linux, debian, .net-core

I have some problems calling commands from a Linux .net core consol application.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim PI As New ProcessStartInfo

    Using Proc As New Process
        With PI
            .FileName = "cat"
            .Arguments = "/etc/*-release"
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .CreateNoWindow = True
        End With
        Proc.StartInfo = PI
        Proc.Start()
        PI = Nothing
        Console.Write(Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
    End Using
End Sub
```

I get this error:

```
cat: '/etc/*-release': No such file or directory
```

It work if I disable redirection and set UseShellExecute = True, but I would like to be able to use the output in my code.

Comment: If you want to avoid using a shell, then you'll have to replicate the work the shell does to expand `/etc/*-release`.  Not that familiar with the language, but perhaps it has a wrapper or equivalent for the Unix C `glob()` function?

Comment: I didn't put to much thought about what was really happening. I just expected ´cat´ to do the "file search" and not the shell......but I see the logic now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh....got it!

I just have to use `bash -c ""cat ""/etc/*-release""""`

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim PI As New ProcessStartInfo

    Using Proc As New Process
        With PI
            .FileName = "bash"
            .Arguments = "-c ""cat ""/etc/*-release"""""
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .CreateNoWindow = True
        End With
        Proc.StartInfo = PI
        Proc.Start()
        PI = Nothing
        Console.Write(Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what those quotes really mean, but they look wacky. The string you pass to `-c` should be `cat /etc/*-release` without any additional internal quotes. In e.g. Python, this would be `subprocess.call(['bash', '-c', 'cat /etc/*-release'])` if that helps to see what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command like

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

The linux shell (bash, probably) evaluates each argument, then calls the program with the evaluated arguments. Simple words evaluate to themselves, but variables (like `$SOME_ARGUMENT`) and patterns (like `*`) evaluate to the values and file names. So the shell really evaluates the above into (assuming there is just one file):

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

And so the `cat` program just gets that one argument - without any globs like `*`.

If you want to emulate that behaviour in your program, you need to set `UseShellExecute` to `True`.

Or, perhaps you can do the evaluation yourself. APIs like `Directory.EnumerateFiles` let you do that:

```
 Dim textFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("/etc/", "*-release")
```

Then you need to walk this collection and use the exact file name as your `.Arguments` value.

Edit: But to go a bit further, why are you even trying to do this? If you have read the file completely, why call `cat`. Why not just `Console.WriteLine()` the file itself rather than calling `cat`?

Comment: I'm making a admin tool which will call a lot of different commands, and I made a function to call whenever I want to fire a command `CallCMD(EXE as string, Args as strings()) as string`. The output need to be saved to a string for further handling. That doesn't seem possible setting `UseShellExecute` to `True`. `cat /etc/*-release` is just an example....I would like it to support any command that I work in the bash shell.